# SQL Subqueries - Exists – Any - All

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a problem facing this subquery SQL exercice,using Northwind DB:

```
**16.
From order number 10251 show employee's name,company's name, order's  
date,name of each product,quantity,unit price and  
final price (= unitprice * quantity – unitprice*quantity*discount)
**
```

The following is my attempt of a solution, each of the subqueries work fine by their own,giving the expected result but it fails when combined together in the same query

```
select 
 (select FirstName from Employees where EmployeeID=Orders.EmployeeID)as 'Name',
 (select Customers.CompanyName from Customers where  Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID)'Company name' ,
 (select Products.ProductName,Products.UnitPrice,
         [Order Details].Quantity,
         (Products.UnitPrice*[Order Details].Quantity-Products.UnitPrice*[Order Details].Quantity*[Order Details].Discount) 
 AS 'Final Price' from Products 
 INNER JOIN [Order Details] on Products.ProductID= [Order Details].ProductID 
 WHERE [Order Details].OrderID=10251),
Orders.OrderDate
from Orders 
where OrderID=10251
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is an English-only site and all the questions and answers must be in English. You might consider posting your question to [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) instead, but if you'd like it to remain here please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68659832/edit) your question and translate it to English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not in English.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your query was failing because the third subquery (for Final Price) was returning a relation, as opposed to a scalar value.

I've re-written the query in a form that opts for joins rather than subqueries. Subqueries can be useful but I think using joins here makes the query little easier to read and work with.

```
select firstName as Name, 
  C.companyName as CompanyName, 
  P.UnitPrice * OD.Quantity 
    - (P.UnitPrice * OD.Quantity * OD.Discount) 
  as FinalPrice
from Orders as O
  left join Employees as E
    on E.employeeId = O.employeeId
  left join Customers as C
    on C.customerId = O.customerId
  left join [Order Details] as OD
    on OD.orderId = O.orderId
  left join Products as P
    on P.productId = OD.produtId
```